# How am I able to specifically print out the even numbers inside the array without interchanging or mixing them up?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  
    int nums[100] = {
        2, 3, 5, 100, 7, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4,
        76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 54, 68, 61, 34, 33,
        44, 49, 100, 5, 2, 87, 34, 33, 2, 1,
        4, 5, 8, 2, 1, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1,
        88, 22, 23, 33, 48, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52,
        45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11,
        11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 100,
        1000, 2001, 3000, 4001, 5000, 6001, 7000, 8001, 9000, 10001
    };
    for(int nums=2; nums<=100; nums++)
    {
        if(nums%2==0){
            printf("%d - I love Coding\n", nums);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
2 - I love Coding
4 - I love Coding
.
.
100 - I love coding
```

but it should be

```
2 - I love Coding
100 - I love Coding
4 - I love Coding
.
.
.
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: You should use a different name for the index ! (and start it at 0)

Comment: Try to run your code through a debugger and put a breakpoint on the print. That should show you what went wrong.

Comment: @LouisCloete Where can I download a debugger? I'm really new into programming.

Comment: @InnocentHaru you probably have already a debugger. What is your platform/IDE/OS/compiler/environnement?

Answer (score 2):

Two issues here.  Your loop counter has the same name as the array, so it *masks* the array from being seen.  Also, you're checking if the loop counter is divsible by 2, not the members of the array.

The loop counter should have a name different from the array.  It should run from 0 to 99 (since those are the valid array indices for an array of size 100), and you need to check the actual array members.

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    if(nums[i]%2==0){
        printf("%d - I love Coding\n", nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'm just new to programming

Answer (score 1):

You are checking and printing the index of the numbers, not the numbers within the array itself.

Change your code into:

```
    for(int index=2; index<100; index++)
    {
        if(nums[index]%2==0){
            printf("%d - I love Coding\n", nums[index]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `index` start at 0?

Comment: The author started his index at 2, I suppose he had a good reason for that.

Comment: So `if(nums%2==0)` is also a good reason? ;-). But he wants to print the _even_ numbers of the array, with `index` starting at 2 he will miss the very first number (2).